# Echarts: How to disable zoom and animation in echarts treemap?

Tags: echarts

[link to example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=treemap-simple)

In this example, I would like to fix treemaps position and disable zoom on mouse-scroll.

I would also like to prevent the animation when we click on a section of treemap.

I have tried to use 'zoomLock: true' and 'animation: false' in the options but couldnt achieve what i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `roam: 'move'` to disable zoom on mouse-scroll and u can try using `nodeClick: false` to prevent the animation when you click on a section of treemap

```
series: [
    {
      roam: 'move',
      nodeClick: false,
      ...
    }
]
```